# MySQL Floating Point Value Query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather strange problem with a floating point value in a table.   In my PRODUCT table I have a MIN_QUANTITY field which contains 0, 0.01, 0.25 and 1 as values.  I wanted to know how many of the rows had 0.01 as the MIN_QUANTITY field, so I used this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT WHERE MIN_QUANTITY = 0.01;
```

The query returned 0.   This is plain wrong, because there are roughly 1,200 instances of 0.01 in this field.   So I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT WHERE MIN_QUANTITY = 0.25;
```

This query duly returned 2,105 which is the right count.

I've been reading that MySQL sometimes does funny things with floating point values, but surely a straight count of an uncalculated value in a field should return the right number - or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: what data_type is `MIN_QUANTITY`

Comment: It's a float data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've discovered why floating point numbers are not a good idea for storing exact amounts.  Use `decimal` instead.  This is a fixed-point representation.

If you cannot change data types in tables, then add a tolerance and use `between`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE MIN_QUANTITY between 0.1 - 0.0001 and 0.25 + 0.0001;
```

With this formulation, you can still use an index on `MIN_QUANTITY`.  If you were to do something like this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE cast(MIN_QUANTITY as decimal(10, 2)) = 0.1;
```

then you would lost the ability to take advantage of an index.

Comment: Yes, I found that I could get the correct count doing something like this - but I couldn't really understand why I have to do that!   Fortunately there's no index on the field, so I don't have to worry about that.   Thanks for the advice.